# Python Lists help, no duplicates in list

Tags: python, list

```
CheckList = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5', 'hello', 'hello1']
AlreadyChecked = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
NextCheck = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']


while(CheckList):
    ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
    while(ToCheck in AlreadyChecked and CheckList):
        ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
    AlreadyChecked.append(ToCheck)
    while(ToCheck in NextCheck and CheckList):
        ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
    NextCheck.insert(0, ToCheck)

print(NextCheck)
```

This code is printing out...

```
['hello', 'hello5', 'hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']
```

What I need to happen:

- NextCheck should have no duplicates once it is being printed.
- NextCheck should have everything in CheckList, no duplication of course
- Once `while(CheckList)` is done executing, everything in NextCheck should be somewhere in AlreadyChecked

Unfortunately, as indicated by the print statement, I get repeats in NextCheck..

Any help? :/

Comment: Are you sure your code is correctly indented?

Comment: Why do you need both `AlreadyChecked` and `NextCheck`? Also, `ToCheck in AlreadyChecked and CheckList` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your list to a `set()`

```
lst = ["A", "B", "C", "C", "B"]
print(list(set(lst)))
>>> ["A", "B", "C"]
```

To change the list just do

```
lst = set(lst)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `set()` function be printing a set?

Comment: set() makes a set of a list by removing all duplicates. Try the code out.

Comment: No, I mean in your example, you are showing the `print(set(lst))` is printing a list, but it should print a set (enclosed in `{}` ) . And Set makes a set, not a list :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed some indentation. Try pasting this and see if the problem is fixed.

```
CheckList = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5', 'hello', 'hello1']
AlreadyChecked = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4']
NextCheck = ['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']


while(CheckList):
    ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
while(ToCheck in AlreadyChecked and CheckList):
    ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
AlreadyChecked.append(ToCheck)
while(ToCheck in NextCheck and CheckList):
    ToCheck = CheckList.pop()
    NextCheck.insert(0, ToCheck)
print(NextCheck)
```

Comment: if I use that, I got the following print statement.. `['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']`.. it is missing 'hello5'